# Create aws_launch_templates from Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm attempting to migrate from launch configs to launch templates.

I edited the resource from `aws_launch_config` to `aws_launch_template` in Terraform and ran

```
terraform apply
```

The job giving errors like:

```
Error: module.create_launch_templates.module.myapp.aws_launch_template.launch_template:
Provider doesn't support resource: aws_launch_template
```

I'm running the following versions:

```
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.aws v1.9.0
+ provider.template v2.0.0
```

The provider version is the most current 1.X version.  Do I need to upgrade to version 2.X?  Is version 2.x even available?

EDIT:  I see from my other post version 2.x isn't yet available.

Comment: 1.9.0 is not the most current version at all. What makes you think that is the case? https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md shows 1.57.0 is available.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the [AWS provider is 1.57](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).  You should upgrade your version, 1.9 is really, really, really old and likely predates the release of launch templates. You can upgrade the provider version by running `terraform init -upgrade` as seen in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/init.html#upgrade).

Version 2.0 of the provider is not yet available and I suspect it will be ready for Terraform version .12, but that's just a guess.